# How to diagnose 'gs' failure converting eps to pdf as part of pdflatex

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps, ghostscript

I'm creating a beamer presentation using a custom theme with company logos on the frametitle and footer of the pages.  I've got these in EPS format and the resulting document does generate correctly with the images as I expect them.

The problem is that as part of the run, the following 'gs' message appears on the command line:

```
Error: /undefined in II*
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_
push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1910   1
   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop
   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--  
 --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1168/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:96/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 9.02: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

I've managed to work out what file was causing this by deleting each
????-eps-converted-to.pdf in turn until the message appears, and then
I've run ps2eps on the file.

So my question is really two parts:

1. Most importantly, how could I have diagnosed which file was causing the problem without having to resort to trial and error?
2. Less so, how is it that the images appear to be OK in the final document?

Comment: Can you make the offending `eps` file available for download?

Comment: Possibility 1: TeX special characters in the filename. Possibility 2: It seems that the `epstopdf` package has been invoked. This usually runs a restricted version of `epstopdf` that invokes `gs` in safe mode. It is possible that this prevents `gs` from accessing some special fonts in the EPS file.

Comment: @IanThompson: I am probably being overly cautious but as the image forms part of our company branding I would need to check that I can make it available.  The .eps was created using Adobe Illustrator.  I could grep for things if you think it would be useful?

Comment: @Dan: The name of the file is 'Strapline.eps' - but what you say about the fonts could well be the issue.

Comment: @RichardCorden --- Adobe Illustrator is the work of Satan, so it's difficult to know what to look for. If I had the file I might recognise something troublesome, but then again I might not. One possibility is garbage at the head or foot of the file. The first and last lines should be `%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-1.2` and `%EOF`, respectively. If there is anything before/after these, try deleting it. I would probably save the edited file with a different name, as Illustrator may not like the result.

Comment: Commenting on this old thread in case anyone else comes across it while Googling like I did.  You may want to check that whatever software you use to create the EPS file does not include an embedded TIFF preview -- at least, turning off that option fixed the problem for me (using Sibelius music notation software, pdflatex, Mac OS X).